# jQuery selector inside the each() method

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets say that I have a HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="aaa"><span>1</span></div>
<div class="aaa"><span>2</span></div>
<div class="aaa"><span>3</span></div>
<div class="aaa"><span>4</span></div>
```

With `$('.aaa span')` I can select all span elements.
With `$('.aaa').each()` I can iterate over the div elements.
My question is how to select the span in each div from inside the each function like:

```
$('.aaa').each(function(index, obj){
    x = selector_based_on_obj // x equal to the current div`s span
})
```

Comment: what? <div class=".aaa"> ???

Comment: I think that should be `<div class="aaa">`.

Comment: type mistake, my fault (

Comment: Your `x` variable is an implicit global if you're omitting the `var` keyword. You should add that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

easiest way is this, if you want all the elements

```
$('.aaa span');
```

jquery can nest selectors just like css can. also, if for some reason you need to loop

```
$('.aaa').each(function(){
    x = $(this).find('span');
});
```

that will set x as the elements as a jquery object.

Comment: You're creating a global variable `x` here. Probably not what you intended.

Comment: I followed the example, i'm not sure if Illian was intending to create a global variable or not, so i simply repeated his scenario to not add confusion.

Comment: @Jeremy B.: Omitting the `var` keyword makes the variable an implicit global.

Comment: @elusive, yes I know. please refer to Illians question, he has x = selector_based... I simply finished his thought. whether or not it is a global variable isn't really important here.

Comment: @Jeremy B.: Right. That is why i upvoted this answer anyway. I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: Jeremy is right, I wrote it that way and he just follow it and finished my example, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`$(obj).find('span')` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the light speed answer, I knew there was a simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.aaa').each(function() {
  var x = $('span', this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.aaa').each(function(index, obj){
    var x = $(this).find('span');
    $(x).doSomething();
})
```

or more prgramatically:

```
$('.aaa').each(function(index, obj){
    $(this).find('span').doSomething();
})
```

Comment: Are you assigning `$(x)`? I do not think that this is possible.

Comment: @elusive, correct. x itself is a jquery object, so calling jquery on it would not be necessary.

Comment: @Jeremy B.: That is not what i meant initially (@FatherStorm corrected that already; it was `$(x) = $(this).find('span');`), but it is true what you mention. You would not need to wrap `x` again. `x.something();` will do, too.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your actual markup, you can easily use the [native property `firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.firstChild).

```
$('.aaa').each(function(){
    var x = this.firstChild
});
```

It is a [widely supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t72) property.