# length of li elements Angular and jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

I need your help. I tried this code which works but works not how I want.

```
$("ul").each(function(){
  let thisClass = $(ul).find('.className')
  if(thisClass.length >= 2){
    thisClass.addClass('done');
  }
});
```

It counted together all elements what I do not want. I want to count separately but I do not know how can goes.

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

Please help me if you can.
Thanks.

Comment: I am having a hard time making sense of the question. But you should be getting an error in your browser because the code uses an undefined variable (`ul`). I think you want `let thisClass = $(this).find('.className');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery selector inside the each() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381228/jquery-selector-inside-the-each-method)

Comment: Do not combine jQuery with Angular. You will get unexpected results in both frameworks and it will probably break Angular.

Comment: what is the variable "ul" ???

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to use jQuery with Angular, re-think!

Check the code where that list is rendering, and you will have the list of items.
Just get the length of those items.

You are rendering two list means two different variables

```
list1.length
list2.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
$("ul").each(function(i,v){  
  let thisClass =$(v).find('.className')  
  if(thisClass.length >= 2){
    thisClass.addClass('done');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you man. It is working with right functionality

Comment: You're welcome. You should now analyse all answers and accept one, no need to let a question opened when it's solved.